# Openlayers 3: Hover effect below top layer with labels?

Tags: openlayers

I am using OpenLayers 3 and I want to have a hover effect of a polygon layer below the top layer with labels. I can arrange the order of the layers that the labels are on top of the polygon, but unfortunately, the hover effect (pointerMove) jumps on top of the labels. Is there a way to fix that?

I created a fiddle with a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/a4kL9441/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use select interaction, an overlay is created with the hover effect, that's why the label's tile are covered.

So, set style on feature on `pointermove`. [A working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/38e2hut1/1/).

Comment: Dear Jonatas,
thanks for your efforts. This works perfect. Besides the hover event I also added a click event: http://jsfiddle.net/a4kL9441/7/

Comment: I'm glad to help. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

heres a working example without ol.interaction.select:
http://jsfiddle.net/a4kL9441/5/

but how to do that with ol.interaction.select I don´t know

Comment: Thanks Basti, 
that looks already very promising. However, if I have more than 1 polygon in the layer where the hover should take place, all of them are highlighted. Have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/a4kL9441/6/

Comment: sorry, don´t have much time at the moment, but maybe this example could help you http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/examples/vector-layer.js